# How to specify regularization parameter (L1 or L2) for a feed forward neural network in R using the mxnet package?

Tags: r, neural-network, deep-learning, mxnet

I am using R mxnet package. Here is the code block that I am currently using. But I am not sure how to specify regularization.

```
dpLnModel <- mx.model.FeedForward.create(symbol             = out,
                                         X                  = trainX,
                                         y                  = trainY,
                                         ctx                = mx.cpu(),
                                         num.round          = numIter,
                                         eval.metric        = mx.metric.rmse,
                                         array.batch.size   = 50,
                                         array.layout       = "rowmajor",
                                         verbose            = TRUE,
                                         optimizer          = "rmsprop",
                                         eval.data          = list(data  = testX,
                                                                   label = testY
                                         ),
                                         initializer        = mx.init.normal(initValVar),
                                         epoch.end.callback = mx.callback.log.train.metric(5, logger)
)
```

Comment: What do the docs say? Seems like either the option is given in the docs or if not then presumably it's not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @leezu's answer says, you need to set weight decay to get L2 regularisation. In the R API, the argument you need is `wd` e.g.

```
dpLnModel <- mx.model.FeedForward.create(symbol             = out,
                                         X                  = trainX,
                                         y                  = trainY,
                                         ctx                = mx.cpu(),
                                         num.round          = numIter,
                                         eval.metric        = mx.metric.rmse,
                                         array.batch.size   = 50,
                                         array.layout       = "rowmajor",
                                         verbose            = TRUE,
                                         optimizer          = "rmsprop",
                                         wd                 = 0.00001)
```

I think you can include any arguments from `mx.opt.rmsprop`. Note that the documentation there says that the default value of `wd` is zero i.e. no regularisation.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `weight_decay` option of your optimizer. Weight decay is equivalent to adding a global l2 regularizer to the parameters.

```
optimizer = mx.SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.00001)
```

I am not that familiar with the R API, but judging from the Python API I would expect you to specify the optimizer in `mx.fit(model, optimizer, train_provider, n_epoch=20, eval_data=eval_provider)` where the first argument is an `mx.FeedForward` model instead of in `mx.FeedForward.create`.

Please see the docs for more information: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/mxnet-test/latest/mxnet-test.pdf